# Strikethough labels when data is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have the following code:

```
app.drawRSCWeightCharts = function() {
var ctx = document.getElementsByClassName('rscWeightChart');
var Charts = [];

if (ctx.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < ctx.length; i++) {
        var id = ctx[i].getAttribute('id');
        var rscWeightChart = new Chart(ctx[i], {
            type: 'pie',
            fill: true,
            data: eval(id + 'Data'),
            options: {
                animation: {
                    animateScale: true
                },
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        });
        rscWeightChart.resize();
        Charts.push(rscWeightChart);
    }
    $('.toggleLegend').click(function (button) {
        if (button.target.id.substr(0, 6) !== 'toggle') {
            button.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } else {
            button.preventDefault();
            var button_id = button.target.id;
            button_id = button_id.replace(/\D/g, '');

            Charts.forEach(function (c) {
                if (('rscWeightChart' + button_id) === c.chart.canvas.id) {
                    c.data.datasets.forEach(function(ds) {
                        ds.hidden = !ds.hidden;
                    });
                    c.update();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This code hides all data in a pie chart when a button is clicked. Unfortunately no strikethrough is applied at the items in the legend. Shouldn't this happen by default when a dataset is hidden? I have tried to hide the legenItems by using the following code before the c.update() function:

```
c.legend.legendItems.forEach(function (li) {
                        li.hidden = !li.hidden;
                    });
```

This didn't work. Anyone knows why the legend items aren't striken through when the datasets are set to hidden = true? If i apply this code to a bar chart, the labels are striken through without any problems. It looks like the problem is in the pie chart or strikethrough is not supported for pie charts...? I made a example of the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/djne09qy/). When the "toggle"-button is clicked, the chart data is hidden, but no labels are striken through.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rscWeightChart.getDatasetMeta(0).data` instead of `rscWeightChart.data.datasets`.

You can [check updaeted fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/djne09qy/14/)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your code is hiding the entire dataset not each label within the dataset.

I've made a simple example below and have commented the code, I hope it makes sense.

If you look at the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getdatasetmetaindex) you will see that `getdatasetmeta()` is needed to get the metadata from inside the object.

> Looks for the dataset that matches the current index and returns that metadata. This returned data has all of the metadata that is used to construct the chart.

```js
let rscWeightChart = new Chart($('.rscWeightChart'), {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      hidden: false
    }]
  }
});

for (let data of rscWeightChart.data.datasets) {
  /* setting this to false will hide the entire chart, 
  but each label will not know that it is hidden */
  console.log(`Entire chart: ${data.hidden}`);
}

for (let data of rscWeightChart.getDatasetMeta(0).data) {
  /* setting this to false will hide each label,
  this will lead to each label gaining a strikethrough */
  console.log(`Each label: ${data.hidden}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<canvas class="rscWeightChart"></canvas>
```